# How to receive two or more forms in a function in django

Tags: python, html, django, forms

As the title says, i am working with two forms in a template.

And i was wondering if there is a way to send two or more forms to save it to the function. Becuase i dont know how can i "detect" the correct form that has to save.

This is my two forms:

**Form 1 from the 'enterprise'instance**

```
<form method="POST" action='' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
          <h4><strong>Datos de empresa:</strong></h4>
          <!--Foto del miembro de equipo-->
          <h6><strong>Subir logo:</strong></h6>
          <input type="file" name="image_path">

              <!--Full name-->
                <div class="form-group row">

                  <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                    <strong>Nombre de empresa:</strong>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                    <strong>Número de teléfono:</strong>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                    <input class= "form-control" type="text" name="name" maxlength="20"  value="{{enterprise.name}}">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <input class= "form-control" type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" name="phone_number" value="{{enterprise.phone_number}}">
                  </div>
                </div>

        <!--Username and email is same in this case-->
                <strong>Correo electrónico:</strong>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class= "form-control" type="email" name="email" value="{{enterprise.email}}" >
                </div>

        <!--Date of birth-->
                <strong>Fecha de fundación:</strong>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class= "form-control" type="date" name="date" value="{{enterprise.date}}" >
                </div>

        <!--Direction-->
                <strong>Dirección:</strong>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea class= "form-control"  rows="6" name="direction" 
                  value="{{enterprise.direction}}">{{enterprise.direction}}</textarea>
                </div>

        <!--Description-->
                <strong>Descripción de empresa:</strong>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea  class="form-control" rows="6" type="text" name="description" value="{{enterprise.description}}">{{enterprise.description}}</textarea>
                </div>

        <!--Employees-->
                <strong>Número de empleados (aproximado):</strong>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class= "form-control" type="number" name="employees" min=1 value="{{enterprise.employees}}">
                </div>

        <!--Button-->
            <hr>
              <button class="btn btn-primary " type="submit">Guardar cambios</button>
      </form>
```

**Form 2 from the 'contactdata'instance**

```
<form method="post" action='' enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            Define cuál es tu visión y objetivo:
                                            <textarea class= "form-control" rows="6" type="text" name="vision" placeholder=""></textarea>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 ">
                                      <img src="{% static 'img/meta-300x300.jpg'%}" alt="" width="210px" height="210px">
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        ¿Cuál es tu horario de atención al cliente?
                                          <input class= "form-control" type="text" name="vision" placeholder="Ejemplo: Lunes a viernes de 7:30am a 6:00pm.">
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <img src="{% static 'img/750x450.png'%}" alt="" width="300px" height="200px">
                                              <strong><p>Resolución recomendada: 750x450px.</p></strong>
                                            <input type="file" name="vision">
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                          <h5><strong>Foto de cabecera:</strong></h5>
                                      <h7>¡Anímate a subir una foto de cabecera!, al hacerlo transmites mayor confianza a los usuarios, puede ser una foto de tu equipo, lugar de tu trabajo, logotipo o alguna foto de portada que vaya de acuerdo con lo que ofrezcas.</h7>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary " type="submit">Guardar cambios</button>
                                    </form>
```

As you can see, thats my two forms from the template.

I tried to do it, but i get the error full_clean() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' when i try to save one of the forms...

The error is specifically in the line

```
if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
```

when i try to validated the two forms..

```
def edit_design(request):
clean_designs()
contact = contactData.objects.get(id=0)
temp = Templates.objects.get(temp_selected=True)
enterprise = enterprisedata.objects.get(id=0)
members = teamMembers.objects.filter(existencia=True)
design = Available_design_page(isSelected=True)
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = EnterpriseForm(instance=enterprise)
    form2 = ContactForm(instance=contactData)
else:
    form = EnterpriseForm(request.POST, instance=enterprise)
    form2 = ContactForm(request.POST, instance=contactData)
    if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form2.save()
        return redirect('adminview:save_page')
    else:
        diccionario=request.POST
        print('es invalido: ', diccionario)
    return redirect('adminview:edit_design')
contexto = {'form':form,
            'form2':form2,
            'members':members,
            'design':design,
            'enterprise':enterprise,
            'contact':contact,
            }
return render(request, 'adminview/edit_design.html', contexto)
```

If anyone can help me i appreciate-

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the two forms (below is pseudocode):

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    form1 = EnterpriseForm(instance=enterprise)
    form2 = OtherForm(#initialize as you need to)
else:
    form1 = EnterpriseForm(request.POST, instance=enterprise)
    form2 = OtherForm(request.POST, instance=#whatever)

if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
   form1.save()
   form2.save()
   #do other things

context = {'form1': form1,
          'form2': form2,
          #etc
```

and in your template, you need to make sure you show them both, like

```
{{ form1.as_p }}
{{ form2.as_p }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i am avoiding using generic forms like form.as_p.. I have tried to put the function like you did, but i get the error "full_clean() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self', when i try to save the form1

Comment: Really can't say much without seeing the code, templates, and full error. Try using the debugger and/or python env to work with your forms & pass test data (and print output) into your view & forms.

Comment: From the templates you have above, it looks like your form actions aren't set. Mine usually have the url for the view, like: <form action="{% url 'object-create' %}" method="post">

Comment: Ok, i edited the question. As you can see i did what you told me. I get the error full_clean() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' when i try to save the forms, please check it, and hope you can help me :)

Comment: A couple of things: 1) you're using an instance of enterprisedata (enterprise), but the model of contactData when you initialize your forms, and 2) I believe the form retrieval in the POST should *just* be initialized from the request.POST, not the request.POST and an initial instance (EnterpriseForm(request.POST), *not* EnterpriseForm(request.POST, instance=enterprise) ).

Comment: However, I may not be familiar with the Django version you're using, the rest of your codebase, and the error (you haven't provided the stacktrace). I gave some suggestions on how to debug w/ my earlier comments; your question of how to get two forms in one view is answered as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Yes, i will create another question. Ty